# Having Issue on Getting One of The Checkbox Value With Switch Case

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at this snippet and let me know wny the selection of `D + F` or `D + E`  or anything with `D` is not working (Except of selecting `C + D`)

```js
var selectedETargetNum;
$('input:checkbox[name=projectsWith]').on('change', function() {
    var val = '';
    $('input:checkbox[name=projectsWith]:checked').each(function() {
        val += $(this).val();
    });
    switch (val) {
        case 'c':
            selectedETargetNum = val;
            console.log(selectedETargetNum);
            break;
        case 'd':
            selectedETargetNum = val;
            console.log(selectedETargetNum);
            break;
        case 'e':
            selectedETargetNum = val;
            console.log(selectedETargetNum);
            break;
        case 'f':
            selectedETargetNum = val;
            console.log(selectedETargetNum);
            break;
        case 'cd':
            selectedETargetNum = val;
            console.log(selectedETargetNum);
            break;
        case 'ce':
            selectedETargetNum = val;
            console.log(selectedETargetNum);
            break;
        case 'cf':
            selectedETargetNum = val;
            console.log(selectedETargetNum);
            break;
        case 'de':
            selectedETargetNum = val;
            console.log(selectedETargetNum);
            break;
        case 'df':
            selectedETargetNum = val;
            console.log(selectedETargetNum);
            break;
        case 'ef':
            selectedETargetNum = val;
            console.log(selectedETargetNum);
            break;
        case 'cde':
            selectedETargetNum = val;
            console.log(selectedETargetNum);
            break;
        case 'cef':
            selectedETargetNum = val;
            console.log(selectedETargetNum);
            break;
        case 'cdf':
            selectedETargetNum = val;
            console.log(selectedETargetNum);
            break;
        case 'def':
            selectedETargetNum = val;
            console.log(selectedETargetNum);
            break;
        case 'cdef':
            selectedETargetNum = val;
            console.log(selectedETargetNum);
            break;
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="c1" class="" role="">
      <div class="">
      <div class="">C</div>
        <div class=""> <input type="checkbox" value="c" name="projectsWith" id="c1" class=""/> <span></span></div>
      </div>
</label>
    
<label for="c2" class="" role="">
      <div class="">
      <div class="">E</div>
        <div class=""> <input type="checkbox" value="e" name="projectsWith" id="c2" class=""/> <span></span></div>
      </div>
</label>

<label for="c3" class="" role="">
      <div class="">
      <div class="">F</div>
        <div class=""> <input type="checkbox" value="f" name="projectsWith" id="c3" class=""/> <span></span></div>
      </div>
</label>

<label for="c55" class="" role="">
      <div class="">
      <div class="">D</div>
       <div class=""> <input type="checkbox" value="d" name="projectsWith" id="c55" class=""/> <span></span></div>
      </div>
</label>
```

Comment: Because strings are ordered? What exactly what you trying to accomplish? The code seems overly verbose.

Comment: what I need is if a user selected all checkboxes the `selectedETargetNum` must be `cefd` or if user selects `E+F+D` it must be `efd` but this is not happening! only when I select the `D`

Comment: `d` is the last checkbox. In your switch you have `cdef`, which is not the real order. Check that out.

Comment: @pablito.aven, thanks I got this part and working but how about `E+F+D`

Comment: In your switch you have `def` where you should have `efd`. Have you read your code?

Comment: Thanks pablito, it fixed now!

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that during check for each checkbox clicked, the string is constructed based on the sequence on which the checkbox appears. 
In order to fix it, you would need to isolate the items checked before and then look for any new item checked.

UPDATED :

```
var selectedETargetNum;
var val = "";
$('input:checkbox[name=projectsWith]').on('change', function() {
    $('input:checkbox[name=projectsWith]').each(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked"))
        {
          if(val.indexOf($(this).val()) == -1)
           val += $(this).val();
        }
        else
        {
           val = val.replace($(this).val(),"");
        }
    });

    alert("This is checked sequence : " + val);
});
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/gcfLso5s/3/

Comment: Thanks DinoMyte but this is not functioning on de-selecting!